# Open unix style paths "/mnt/c/..." on Windows 10 with linux subsystem

Tags: windows, winapi, gdb

On Windows 10 with linux subsystem you can compile project with debug information that contains paths like this "/mnt/c/" using mingw compiler.

And software like gdbgui tries to open such file using function like 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew

and of course it fails

What is the proper way to write such software in cross platform way?

Edit: Possible workarounds

1. edit compiled binary and change paths
2. create small utility and hook winapi FileOpen function

Comment: Embed [SourceLink](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink) annotations into the PDBs, and have it point at a source configuration management repository.

Comment: I would think you might also be able to do something with junctions

Comment: The problem here is that you're mixing toolchains. You're using the Linux subsystem `mingw`, not the Win32 subsystem `mingw.exe`. The latter will produce `C:\...` paths that `gdbgui.exe` understands.